# MacOS Homebrew: How to override *specific* system binaries

Tags: shell, path, homebrew

I've installed Homebrew 3.3.1, followed by `brew install git`, and my resulting path looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/brew/bin
```

Naturally, this path prefers the system git binary. To fix this, I tried prepending the path to the git binary, since I do not want *all* Homebrew binaries to override the system binaries just the Homebrew `git` binary.

```
/opt/brew/bin/git:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/brew/bin
```

However, after opening a new shell, the system `git` binary is still preferred.

```
Camerons-MPB9FDD:~ cameronhudson$ git --version
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)
Camerons-MPB9FDD:~ cameronhudson$ which -a git
/usr/bin/git
/opt/brew/bin/git
```

Is it possible to override a specific binary?

Comment: Side note: [Why not use `which`? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/108618)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `$PATH` can only accept directories. However, you could symlink the git executable to a new directory and add that to your path.